# Matlab guidata handles problems

Tags: matlab

I made a quick test function to test guidata, but whenever I used but3c, I keep getting the "not enough input arguments" error.

Anyone willing to help out with this?

```
function test
clear
clc
figure();
but1 = uicontrol('units','normalized','position',[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2],...
                 'callback',@but1cb);
but2 = uicontrol('units','normalized','position',[0.6,0.6,0.2,0.2],...
                 'callback',@but2cb);
but3 = uicontrol('units','normalized','position',[0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2],...
                 'callback',@but3cb,'string',' ');
    function but1cb(hObject,~,handles)
        a = 1;
        handles.a = 1;
        guidata(hObject, handles)
    end
    function but2cb(hObject,~,handles)
        a = 2;
        handles.a = 2; 
        guidata(hObject, handles)
    end
    function but3cb(hObject,~,handles)
        a = handles.a
        print(a);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest fix is to first get the guidata from hObject

```
function test
   figure();
   but1 = uicontrol('units','normalized','position',[0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2],...
             'callback',@but1cb);
   but2 = uicontrol('units','normalized','position',[0.6,0.6,0.2,0.2],...
             'callback',@but2cb);
   but3 = uicontrol('units','normalized','position',[0.4,0.4,0.2,0.2],...
             'callback',@but3cb,'string',' ');
       function but1cb(hObject,~)        
           a = 1;
           handles = guidata(hObject);
           handles.a = 1;
           guidata(hObject, handles)
       end
       function but2cb(hObject,~)
           handles = guidata(hObject);
           a = 2;
           handles.a = 2; 
           guidata(hObject, handles)
       end
       function but3cb(hObject,~)
           handles = guidata(hObject);
           a = handles.a
           print(a);
       end
   end
```

Comment: Thank you!
I figured it would be something obvious, but not this obvious. I did not actually see a single help file anywhere, that says to get the currently existing handles first. A tad silly. Oh well.

Thank you so muh!